# npm install sqlite3 --build-from-source error with electron

Tags: node.js, sqlite, npm, electron

When trying to use sqlite with electron i've been getting this error in the web console

> Error: Cannot find module       'C:\Users\Alejandro\Documents\Proyectos\format\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\el ectron-v1.4-win32-ia32\node_sqlite3.node'

After reading some posts in the site i've seen that by using

> npm install sqlite3 --build-from-source

I can fix this error, however when i tried to do so i got the following message

> sqlite3@3.1.8 install C:\Users\Alejandro\Documents\Proyectos\format\node_modules\sqlite3
>   node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
>
> C:\Users\Alejandro\Documents\Proyectos\format\node_modules\sqlite3>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Users\Alejandro\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\....\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" clean )  else (node "" clean )
>
> C:\Users\Alejandro\Documents\Proyectos\format\node_modules\sqlite3>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Users\Alejandro\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\....\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\Alejandro\Documents\Proyectos\format\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v48-win32-ia32\node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=C:\Users\Alejandro\Documents\Proyectos\format\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v48-win32-ia32 )  else (node "" configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\Alejandro\Documents\Proyectos\format\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v48-win32-ia32\node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=C:\Users\Alejandro\Documents\Proyectos\format\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v48-win32-ia32 )
>
> gyp ERR! configure error
>
> gyp ERR! stack Error: Python executable
>
> "C:\Users\Alejandro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\python.EXE" is v3.5.1, which is not supported by gyp.
>
> gyp ERR! stack You can pass the --python switch to point to Python >= v2.5.0 & < 3.0.0.
>
> gyp ERR! stack     at failPythonVersion (C:\Users\Alejandro\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:454:14)
>
> gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Alejandro\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-
>   gyp\lib\configure.js:443:9
>
> gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:197:7)
>
> gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
>
> gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
>
> gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
>
> gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
>
> gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.14393
>
> gyp ERR! command "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe"
>
> "C:\Users\Alejandro\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=C:\Users\Alejandro\Documents\Proyectos\format\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v48-win32-ia32\node_sqlite3.node" "--module_name=node_sqlite3" "--module_path=C:\Users\Alejandro\Documents\Proyectos\format\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v48-win32-ia32"
>
> gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Alejandro\Documents\Proyectos\format\node_modules\sqlite3
>
> gyp ERR! node -v v6.9.1
>
> gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
>
> gyp ERR! not ok
>
> node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
>
> node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'node-gyp.cmd configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\Alejandro\Documents\Proyectos\format\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v48-win32-ia32\node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=C:\Users\Alejandro\Documents\Proyectos\format\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v48-win32-ia32' (1)
>
> node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess. (C:\Users\Alejandro\Documents\Proyectos\format\node_modules\sqlite3\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
>
> node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
>
> node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
>
> node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
>
> node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
>
> node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.14393
>
> node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\Alejandro\Documents\Proyectos\format\node_modules\sqlite3\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\bin\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-
>   build"
>
> node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Alejandro\Documents\Proyectos\format\node_modules\sqlite3
>
> node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v6.9.1
>
> node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.31
>
> node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
>   Failed to execute 'node-gyp.cmd configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\Alejandro\Documents\Proyectos\format\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v48-win32-ia32\node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=C:\Users\Alejandro\Documents\Proyectos\format\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v48-win32-ia32' (1)
>
> npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
>
> npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\Alejandro\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "sqlite3" "--build-from-source"
>
> npm ERR! node v6.9.1
>
> npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>
> npm ERR! sqlite3@3.1.8 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
>
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! Failed at the sqlite3@3.1.8 install script 'node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build'.
>
> npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
>
> npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the sqlite3 package,
>
> npm ERR! not with npm itself.
>
> npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
>
> npm ERR!     node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
>
> npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
>
> npm ERR!     npm bugs sqlite3
>
> npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
>
> npm ERR!     npm owner ls sqlite3
>
> npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\Alejandro\Documents\Proyectos\format\npm-debug.log

I've already tried installing the node-gyp and node-pre-gyp dependancies and still get the same error

Comment: As you can see from the log you've got the wrong Python version installed for `node-gyp`, and you're not building against Electron's Node headers as documented in http://electron.atom.io/docs/tutorial/using-native-node-modules/